# Date/time from the database as a function in my context

Tags: entity-framework-core, c#-9.0

I need a function in my DBContext which tells me the current date/time in the database itself.
SQL has a standard function "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" so getting it is easy.

But I want a function ServerDateTime() in my DBContext and I'm stuck at something like:

```
modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(typeof(PortalContext).GetMethod(nameof(ServerDateTime), ???));
```

So, how do I do this? Or is there a more practical solution to solve this?

(I need the server date/time as the server will be on a different machine and my code wants to know the time difference.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define static class for your functions

```cs
public static class MyDbFunctions
{
    public static DateTime CurrentTimeStamp()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Register `CurrentTimeStamp` function in DbContext

```cs
modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(() => MyDbFunctions.CurrentTimeStamp())
    .IsBuiltIn()
    .HasTranslation(e =>
    {
        return new SqlFragmentExpression("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
    });
```

Use in queries

```cs
query = query.Where(x => x.Date < MyDbFunctions.CurrentTimeStamp());
```

Comment: Almost. I don't just want to use it for queries but also want to display the server date/time. But that results in an exception...

Comment: This doesn't make sense though, since in queries one can use the standard `DateTime.Now`, which is translated to `GET_DATE()`, which is the same as `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. And none work outside queries. So...

Comment: @IvanStoev GET_DATE() is database-specific while CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is standard SQL. Also, the database is running on a different system so I need to know the date/time on the server, not on the current machine. The current machine might not be synchronized with the database server. (And my project has to work for different database servers.)

Comment: @WimtenBrink I'm saying that inside queries standard `DateTime.Now` expression is the right way to get what you need - the database provider will map it to the corresponding database function and execute it server side. Hence no need to map your own `DbFunction`. And outside queries none of the two (standard that I mentioned and the one from the answer) approaches work. That's why the answer makes no sense to me.

Comment: @IvanStoev, thanks for blaming my first and probably last DbFunction :) For me it was surprise that EF Core has unexpected limitations here. Looks like only experts trying to extend queries.

Comment: @IvanStoev Well, if EF Core really does translate DateTime.Now to GET_DATE then that would work. I just need to be 100% sure that it does, no matter which database provider I will be using. That's also why I use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as this a standard SQL command, and not specific to any database.